# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` from my `pushtofirebase` function, even though, everything looks right to me. Would appreciate any kind of help.

Here is the code:

```
export default class RegisterView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pushToFirebase = this.pushToFirebase.bind(this);

  }

  onSubmit = values => {
    var user = {
      firstName: values.fname,
      lastName: values.lname,
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    }

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
      .then(function () {
        this.pushToFirebase(true);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          console.log(errorMessage);
        }
        this.pushToFirebase(false);
      });

    this.pushToFirebase = status => {
      if (status) {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('users/').push(user);
        console.log('im inside pushToFirebase');
        console.log(ref.key);
        this.props.setuserkey;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I should also mention, that I am new to react, been through 3 weeks of solid react development and am still quite new.

Thank you all again for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `pushToFirebase` inside `onSubmit`. Should be

```
export default class RegisterView extends React.Component {

  // make it class property
  pushToFirebase = status => {
      if (status) {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('users/').push(user);
        console.log('im inside pushToFirebase');
        console.log(ref.key);
        this.props.setuserkey;
      }
    }

  onSubmit = values => {
    var user = {
      firstName: values.fname,
      lastName: values.lname,
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    }

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
      .then( () => { // Use arrow function
        this.pushToFirebase(true);
      })
      .catch( (error) => {  // Use arrow function
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          console.log(errorMessage);
        }
        this.pushToFirebase(false);
      });
  }
}
```

Also you don't need to bind arrow function property in constructor.

**UPD** Also you need to replace `function()` handlers with arrow functions to capture `this.`

Comment: this resolved my error, but now im getting another error message when i post

Comment: @helloworld What error message? Update your question.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushToFirebase' of undefined` `> 41 |       this.pushToFirebase(false);` my `firebase.auth().catch` method

Comment: @helloworld OIC. You need to replace normal functions w/ arrows when declaring handlers. Check the updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much!!! good catch, also 1 more thing im trying to update my parent component state in my `pushToFirebase ` function with `this.props.setuserkey;` but its not workig, any ideas? i dont need any event

Comment: @helloworld `this.props.setuserkey` you are only accessing the function. I guess you need to call it `this.props.setuserkey(ref.key)` :)

Comment: called it but no luck on my method in my app.js heres the code `setUserKey = key => {
    console.log('im in setUserKey');
    console.log(key);
    this.setState({ key: key })
  }` in my app.js

Comment: @helloworld IMHO this should be asked as a different question because you need to provide more context. For example you need to show how you pass this property to `RegisterView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173113/discussion-between-hello-world-and-yury-tarabanko).

Comment: `<Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterView} setuserkey={this.setUserKey}/>` here how its being passed

Answer (score 0):

Omit `this` from your function definition. Instead of:

```
this.pushToFirebase = status => {
```

Use:

```
pushToFirebase = status => {
```

and move it into your class instead of onSubmit function.

Also, you don't have to bind your function in constructor since you are using an arrow function here.

Comment: this resolved my error, but now im getting another error message when i post

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined pushtofirebase

The function defination for `pushtofirebase` is missing.

So,there is no property with this name associated with `this` object.Its cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.pushToFirebase = status => {` to just `pushToFirebase = status =>` and move the function to outside of the `onSubmit` function.

And since it is an arrow function you don't have to do `this.pushToFirebase = this.pushToFirebase.bind(this);`
 this line you can remove it

So it should look something like

```
export default class RegisterView extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 }
 pushToFirebase = status => {
   if (status) {
     const ref = firebase.database().ref('users/').push(user);
     console.log('im inside pushToFirebase');
     console.log(ref.key);
     this.props.setuserkey;
   }
 }
```

Comment: this resolved my error, but now im getting another error message when i post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 this.pushToFirebase (status) {
```

Hope this could be helpful for you